# Neo4j Group difference

Tags: neo4j, left-join, difference

Is there any way to directly find the group difference between nodes?

I have a small db with only one kind of node called :`PERSON with attributes {name , city}` and `two relationships :FRIEND  and :LIKES`

I want to find those persons whose ONLY have friends in their city and does not have friends in other cities

I thought about something like :

```
 MATCH (a:PERSON)-[:FRIEND]->(b:PERSON) WHERE a.city=b.city
 AND NOT ((a)-[:FRIEND]-(c) WHERE a.city <> c.city) RETURN 
 DISTINCT(a.city), collect(DISTINCT(a.name)) ORDER BY a.city
```

but seems like you cant anidate `WHERE'S`

Comment: there was already two same questions answered with the same problem in the last two days

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `all` predicate for this:

```
MATCH (a:PERSON)-[:FRIEND]->(b)
WITH a, collect(b) as friends
WHERE all(x in friends WHERE a.city=x.city)
RETURN a
```

Since `City` seems to be an important concept in your domain, consider modelling cities as nodes and not hide them in properties.